# How to configure transactional replication for managed instance as a publisher and a subscriber for two different sql server at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, transactional-replication, azure-sql-managed-instance

The scenario is such that a subscriber is subscribed to transaction replication based publisher (distributor running on publisher).

I then want this subscriber to be a publisher to another subscriber. 
Can I keep the same distributor for this scenario or I have to create another distributor on the subscriber that I want to be publisher to another subscriber?

**I have successfully implemented Transactional replication between azure sql vm (publisher and distributor) and azure sql managed instance(subscriber)** now **I want to perform replication from this managed instance (now subscriber to be publisher) to azure sql database(subscriber)**

Do I need to create distributor on every publisher which is on different servers?

**I want the data changed on azure sql vm to be replicated on azure sql database.**But my azure sql server vm replicating on managed instance and my managed instance should be replicating data to azure sql database.
Can some body help me out?

Comment: You would normally create a new distributor on the republishing subscriber.

Comment: Yes, I implemented the Transactional replication by craeting distributor at new publisher.But I my tables are not able to be viewed from the subscriber and replication is running all good....may I know why so?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Is there a reason you are double-hopping the replication instead of simply configuring your Azure SQL Database as a Push Subscriber from your Azure VM? [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/replication-to-sql-database)

Comment: Yes.The client wants to see this relay type of replication if it works or not.

Comment: Now replication is working but table is not visible on destination(azure sql db) from azure sql managed instance.

Comment: Can I use the subscription database to publish to different subscriber using different distributor on publisher ?

Comment: Please can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you configured your Managed Instance as a Publisher?